# Connect to FTP server with TLS/SSL Implicit Encryption in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ftp, ftps

I have Node.js app, I'm trying to connect to an FTP server and list the folders/files that are in the FTP server folder.

The server is configured with: TLS/SSL Implicit Encryption

Here's my code:

```
async function listFilesInFtpFolder() {
  const client = new ftp.Client()
  client.ftp.verbose = true;
  try {
      await client.access({
          host: ftpConfig.host,
          user: ftpConfig.user,
          password: ftpConfig.password,
          port: ftpConfig.port,
          secure: false
      });

      // ********************** NOTE **********************
      // The execution never reaches here, it gets stuck in the 
      // ... previous statement until it times out
      // ********************** NOTE **********************

      console.log('connected');
      console.log(await client.list())

  }
  catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
  client.close()
}
```

Getting this error:

```
Listening on port 3001
Connected to 155.66.22.88:6610

Error: Timeout (control socket)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\my-app\node_modules\basic-ftp\dist\FtpContext.js:296:58)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:298:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:468:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

The execution never reaches these lines:

```
      console.log('connected');
      console.log(await client.list())
```

It gets stuck waiting for the access method until it times out
For some weird reason the access method reports "Connected"

Note if I use a program like WinSCP (https://winscp.net/) to connect to this FTP server I'm able to connect and see the folders. But for some weird reason I cannot connect from nodejs. I tried many FTP libraries too.

Comment: Anybody knows why I'm not able to connect?

Comment: "The FTP Server is configured with: TLS/SSL Implicit Encryption", but you have set `secure: false` ?

Comment: @BenBeri Same result whether I set it true or false. Here's the documentation for this property: "(property) AccessOptions.secure?: boolean
Use explicit FTPS over TLS. Optional, default is false."

Comment: are you sure about the port?

Comment: @MohammedNagy Yes 100% sure about the port, as I said if I connect using a program like WinSCP it works fine but for some reason it doesn't work from Node.js I can't figure it out for hte life of me.

Comment: Anybody has any idea why this is happening? It's driving me nuts O_o

Comment: Can you try to increase the timeout: new ftp.Client(60000)?

Comment: @JannesBotis Already tried nothing.

Comment: Did u try another ftp library, perhaps like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp They look like they have implicit mode

Comment: @Ralph Yes I have but this library hasn't been maintained in over 5 years the master branch is very buggy, many other devs created other Dev branches and fixed some bugs but still it did not work properly for me, I ended up buying a .NET library, created a .NET WebApi app and called it from my Node app

Comment: You have a point there... especially if there are vulnerabilities... But it is still highly used and it may be your only option...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Node.js does not support *implicit* TLS/SSL.

See for example:
https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp/issues/153

Are you sure that your server does not support *explicit* TLS/SSL?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't control that part, they configured the server with Implicit TLS/SSL, I'm not sure about Node.js Not supporting Implicit TLS/SSL, I don't think Node cares at all, did you mean the library that I was using?

Comment: Did you try the explicit mode?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you post WinSCP log file?

Comment: The Server is configured in Implicit mode I have no choice but to use Implicit mode.

Comment: Do you understand that it's not explicit *or* implicit? That a server can support both modes at the same time? And it is quite unusual for a server to support the implicit mode only? Implicit mode is a non-standard legacy hack that was used decades ago. Only exclicit mode conforms to FTP specification.

Comment: Legacy systems that still use implicity-only still exist and I have to deal with them, I understand it's deprecated but some companies still use that

Comment: Sure, that's true. I just wanted to confirm that you actually tested the explicit mode. + I'm afraid that the FTP class you are using does not support the implicit mode. + As the problem is about the "implicit mode", I suggest you state that more prominently in your question - ideally in the question title + And replace the confusing `secure: false` with `true`.

Comment: I also tried with this one which supports implicit mode: (https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp), I'm able to connect the FTP Server but I cannot list files or upload files to the FTP, it gets stuck in: " File status okay; about to open data connection."

Comment: Can you retrieve the listing using any FTP client running on the same machine/same network?

Comment: I realized almost all FTPS node libraries out there that support implicit are buggy or not maintained properly, I ended up buying an .NET FTP Library works perfectly fine, had to create a separete WebAPI app to call from my Node app

Comment: @Eric Bergman Can you tell me what you bought, I'm finding I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using `ftp` module from npm

according to the document https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp#methods
the `secure` option accepts mixed type, try 'implicit'

> secure - mixed - Set to true for both control and data connection encryption, 'control' for control connection encryption only,
>
> **or 'implicit' for implicitly encrypted control connection (this mode is deprecated in modern times, but usually uses port 990) Default: false**